# Slow Queries on MongoDB 5.0 Native Time-Series Collection

Tags: mongodb, time-series

I was using MongoDB to store some time-series data at 1 Hz.  To facilitate this, my central document represented an hour of data per device per user, with 3600 values pre-allocated at document creation time.  Two drawbacks:

1. every insert is an update.  I need to query for the correct record (by user, by device, by day, by hour), append the latest IoT reading to the list, and update the record.
2. paged queries require complex custom code.  I need to query for a record count of all the data matching my search range, then manually create each page of data to be returned.

I was hoping the MongoDB Native Time-Series Collections introduced in 5.0 would give me some performance improvements and it did, but only on ingestion rate.  The comparison I used is to push 108,000 records into the database as quickly as possible and average the response time, then perform paged queries and get a range for the response time for those.  This is what I observed:

> Mongo Custom Code Solution: 30 milliseconds inserts, 10-20 millisecond
> paged query.
>
> Mongo Native Time-Series: 138 microsecond insert, 50-90 millisecond
> paged query.

The difference in insert rate was expected, see #1 above.  But for paged queries I didn't expect my custom time-series kluge implementation to be significantly faster than a native implementation.  I don't really see a discussion of the advantages to be expected in the Mongo 5.0 documentation.  Should I expect to see improvements in this regard?

Comment: Time-Series Collections are brand new in Mongo 5.0. Perhaps they become better in future releases.